# Neo4j 2.3.0-M01 cypher query from VB.NET failing

Tags: vb.net, neo4j

Recently installed new version of Neo4j on Windows 7 Prof PC.  Able to create nodes using API batch inserts.  Cypher queries from web interface work but now fail from VB.NET code at the line after the comment  'retrieve results of query, which will be in JSon.  This ran okay on the previous Neo4j version (2.2.x)

```
 Public Shared Function DBQuery(URI As String, PostString As String) As DataView
    'runs query and returns JSon results as a dataview
    'Uses POST method to access Neo4j Server API
    Dim S As String = ""
    Dim HttpWReq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URI)
    HttpWReq.Method = "POST"
    HttpWReq.ContentType = "application/json"
    HttpWReq.Accept = "application/json"
    Dim B1() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PostString, 0, Len(PostString))

    'POST query
    'http://blog.micic.ch/net/using-neo4j-graph-db-with-c-net
    HttpWReq.Connection = "Open"
    HttpWReq.ContentLength = B1.Length
    Dim newStream As IO.Stream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream()
    'this method closes stream before calling getResponse
    Using newStream
        newStream.Write(B1, 0, B1.Length)
    End Using

    'retrieve results of query, which will be in JSon 
    Dim HttpWResp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(HttpWReq.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
    HttpWReq.KeepAlive = False
    HttpWReq.Timeout = 15000000

    Dim E As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(HttpWResp.CharacterSet)
    Dim SR As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(HttpWResp.GetResponseStream, encoding:=E)
    S = SR.ReadToEnd  'JSon result
    Return JSonToDV(S)
End Function
```

Documentation for v2.3.0 indicates the need for a different conf file setting, but this is not working.  The documentation is at http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0-M01/server-configuration.html .  The neo4j-server.properties file originally had no entry for org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db.  Adding the suggested line (org.neo4j.server.database.location="C:/Data/Neo4j/UMLS/graph.db") and then the database failed to start.  Would appreciate suggested solutions.

Comment: The error I am receiving is InternalServerError {500}.  Perhaps it is the query?  In the web interface, this runs successfully:MATCH (n:MRCONSO) where n.SAB='SNOMEDCT_US' RETURN n.CUI,n.STR LIMIT 25, but in my VB.NET code, which gives the server error, the Post is using {"query":"MATCH (n:MRCONSO) where n.SAB='SNOMEDCT_US' RETURN n.CUI,n.STR LIMIT 25"}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with Neo4j 2.3.0 but with the VB.NET code.  The corrected code, which works is:

```
  Public Shared Function DBQuery(URI As String, PostString As String, method As EnumLib.WebServiceMethod) As DataView
    'Used for individual API calls; see BulkUpload for other method
    'Uses POST method to access Neo4j Server API
    Dim ID As Long = 0
    Dim HttpWReq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URI)

    Select Case method
        Case EnumLib.WebServiceMethod.POST
            HttpWReq.Method = "POST"
        Case EnumLib.WebServiceMethod.GET
            HttpWReq.Method = "GET"
    End Select
    HttpWReq.ContentType = "application/json"
    HttpWReq.Accept = "application/json"

    Dim B1() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostString, 0, Len(PostString))

    'http://blog.micic.ch/net/using-neo4j-graph-db-with-c-net
    HttpWReq.Connection = "Open"
    Dim S As String = ""
    Try
        HttpWReq.ContentLength = B1.Length
        Dim newStream As IO.Stream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream()
        'this method closes stream before calling getResponse
        Using newStream
            newStream.Write(B1, 0, B1.Length)
        End Using

        Dim HttpWResp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(HttpWReq.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)

        Dim E As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(HttpWResp.CharacterSet)
        Dim SR As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(HttpWResp.GetResponseStream, encoding:=E)
        S = SR.ReadToEnd

    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox("Message: " & vbLf & ex.Message)
        Dim RS As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim SS As String = RS.ReadToEnd
        PostReturnString = "WebException Error: " & ex.Message & vbLf & vbLf & ex.Status & vbLf & vbLf & SS
        ' MsgBox("Status: " & vbLf & ex.Status & vbLf & vbLf & SS)
    End Try
    Return JSonToDV(S)
    End Function
```